# mmenu light is not hiding the #menu and also not moving the menu to the hidden slidein-element (which exists)

Tags: mmenu

I just tried to add mmenu light to a simple default website (like in the example https://mmenujs.com/mmenu-light/tutorial.html). The mobile menu is being generated, but the menu itself is still visible and not moved to the right place (sorry - i'm not sure how to describe it in a better way).

What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

````
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width minimum-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no" />
    <title>My webpage</title>
    <link href="mmenu-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#menu">Open the menu</a>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="Selected"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><span>About us</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/about/history/">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about/team/">The team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about/address/">Our address</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>The title</h1>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="mmenu-light.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener(
        "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const menu = new MmenuLight(
                document.querySelector( "#menu" ),
                "(max-width: 600px)"
            );

            const navigator = menu.navigation();
            const drawer = menu.offcanvas();

            document.querySelector( "a[href='#menu']" )
                .addEventListener( "click", ( evnt ) => {
                    evnt.preventDefault();
                    drawer.open();
                });
        }
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the demo on github:
https://github.com/FrDH/mmenu-light/tree/master/demo

Using the demo from github works.
Using the demo from the tutorial doesn't.

I assume it has to do with the following:

````
            "DOMContentLoaded", () => {```
````